# map with struct as key returns incorrect value

Tags: c++

I have

```
struct data_cell{
    int owner;
    std::vector<int> shares;
};

data_cell** data; //grid, very big
std::map<data_cell, data_cell*> cells; //all uniq cells

bool operator==(const data_cell &b, const data_cell &o) {
    return (b.owner == o.owner && b.shares == o.shares);
}

bool operator<(const data_cell &b, const data_cell &o) {
    return (b.owner < o.owner && b.shares != o.shares);
}

int to_grid(float, float);
```

sometimes when I do:

```
for (int i=0;i<ids.size();i++){//example
    data_cell o=ids[i];
    //some work where fills o.shares
    data[to_grid(x,y)]=(cells[o]?:cells[o]=(new data_cell(o)));
    printf("%d |%d|%d|%d %d\n", s.id, o.owner, cells[o]->owner, data[to_grid(x,y)]->owner, to_grid(x,y));
}
```

I got that o.owner != cells[o]->owner, (printf shows different values), and if I print cells[o] before assign it returns nonzero pointer, but this key doesn't exist in map.

I use gcc-4.6.

what is wrong with this code?

Add1: 
Change to

```
bool operator<(const data_cell &b, const data_cell &o) {
    return (b.owner < o.owner && b.shares < o.shares);
}
```

doesn't help, but

```
bool operator<(const data_cell &b, const data_cell &o) {
    return (b.owner < o.owner && b.shares <= o.shares);
}
```

Add2:
The last version that works(I hope):

```
bool operator<(const data_cell &b, const data_cell &o) {
    return (b.owner < o.owner && b.shares <= o.shares) ||
            (b.owner <= o.owner && b.shares < o.shares);
}
```

May be some additions?

Answer (score 3):

Your `==` and `<` operators have to be such that exactly one of `a < b`, `a == b`, and `b < a` is `true`, and the other two `false`. That is not the case here due to `b.shares != o.shares` in your implementation of `operator<`.

Comment: I'd rather say that only a single of the three expressions should be true at any time.

Comment: @mike.dld Yes that tighter condition must hold. I've amended.

Comment: do I have to set operator < as a.owner<b.owner && a.shares<b.shares?

Comment: This is what you must adhere to: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare , https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings